# New HTML url prefixes after http://www

Tags: url, prefix

I have recently noticed a few sites are implementing prefixes to sites.

example: www.data.cityofchicago.org or www.mobile.smashingmagazine.com

What is the advantage of doing this and how is it accomplished?

Thanks.

Comment: Its called a subdomain. It can show different sites on the same domain. E.g mobile version of smashingmagazinge.com. Also, these have existed for a verrrry long time.

Comment: You mean `www.data.cityofchicago.org` vs. just `data.cityofchicago.org`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subdomain is often used to take advantage of the same origin security policy of browsers. This can be for performance, for security, or both. The same origin policy lets a developer restrict access to cookies stored on the main hostname from the subdomain.

Media files hosted on the subdomain don't have the HTTP cookie header overhead that they would if hosted from the primary hostname, resulting in a performance gain depending on how big the cookies are and how many media files are being requested.

Also, a site can link to user-generated content on a subdomain to offer a level of protection against XSS attacks. With no access to the cookies, there is less for the attacker to exploit. There's a lot more that must be done to secure a site, but every bit helps.

Subdomains let you share cookies when you want too, so they let you have multiple independent sites all share one login for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a subdomain. Using a subdomain, you can, as @sam already said in a comment, use it to have multiple sites on one domain. For example, stackexchange, the network of sites that includes stack overflow, many Q&A sites that are not yet popular enough to have their own domain name, have a subdomain of stackexchange.com. Take a look at [gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) and [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Some sites also use subdomains to direct you to a specific item, such as a specific user. For example, if you want to go to my blog called 'iambigblind', you go to [iambigblind.blogspot.com](http://iambigblind.blogspot.com)

This is often done to make it easier for people to find a certain page. Many people find it easier to remember a subdomain than a path, even when they're both just one element.

If you are hosting a site with a hosting provider that has cpanel, here's a tutorial showing you how to set up a subdomain: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIP_sFESPhQ

If you're directly dealing with an apache server, you should look into how to use virtual hosts: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/